# Angular 2 - Update ngModel inside a custom directive at @HostListener('blur')

Tags: angular, directive

I have a custom directive that only accepts number. When I input 1.2, it is good. But when I type only 1. I want to erase the inputted 1. on blur. I have tried several ways on how to set the value to empty string inside the `onBlur` but still no luck at all. Here is the code snippet:

```
@Output() ngModelChange = new EventEmitter();

constructor(el: ElementRef, public model: NgControl){
 //Instead of NgControl, I have also tried the NgModel but it did not work
 this.el = el.nativeElement;
}

@HostListener('blur', ['$event']) onBlur($event){
 if(isNaN(this.el.value.replace(/(,)/g, '')) || this.el.value[this.el.value.length - 1] === '.' || this.el.value[this.el.value.length - 1] === '-'){
    this.el.value = '';
    this.model.control.updateValue('');
    this.model.viewToModelUpdate('');
    this.ngModelChange.emit('');
 } 
}
```

This does erase the 1. in the input field. But when I print out the value of the `ngModel` that holds the data, the value is 1

In that case, I want to set the ngModel value to empty string. How can I do that inside the blur?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can create and trigger a change event on the element to tell angular to update the model value.

```
let event: Event = document.createEvent("Event");
event.initEvent('input', true, true);
Object.defineProperty(event, 'target', {value: this.el.nativeElement, enumerable: true});
this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(this.el.nativeElement, 'dispatchEvent', [event]);
```

Comment: I'd rather go with `this.ngModelChange.emit('$event);` as in my answer. dispatchEvent may work, however it is part of the testing code, thus I consider ngModelChange the proper way to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

I think the prober solution may be using [**custom form controls**](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html#adding-custom-validation). However I never used them.

Firing `this.change.emit(event);` should do the thing and is working for me. The magic is that you emit the **event** and **not the value** and the changed value must be within event.target.value.

So for example

```
let onChangeCallback = (e) => {
  console.log("change", e );
  this.ngModelChange.emit(e);
  this.change.emit(e)
};
```

so you may like to try:

```
$event.target.value = "",
this.change.emit($event);
```

For detailed reading I figured this blog post as [introduction into angular2 two way data binding](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html) very helpful.